# Why does $(document).getElementbyId not work in this function while just document.getElementbyId works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

This is the function. I am including Jquery library from Google CDN and it is before this script.
{

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  function displayTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    // This gets a "handle" to the clock div in our HTML
    //This does not work???
    var clockDiv = $(document).getElementById('clock');
    //This works though
    var clockDiv = document.getElementById('clock');

    // Then we set the text inside the clock div 
    // to the hours, minutes, and seconds of the current time
    clockDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }

  // This runs the displayTime function the first time
  displayTime();

});
```

}

Comment: because jQuery doesn't have a getElementById method... ??????????

Comment: `$(document).` returns a jQuery object, where as `getElementById` is a method of the `document` object

Comment: In jQuery you could just use the id selector to get the object `var clockDiv = $('#clock');` then `clockDiv.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);`

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, to achieve the same functionality as you would using just the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) for Document with jQuery, you would use a selector instead. As Arun P states, you would do

```
var clockDiv = $('#clock'); // select the div with an ID of clock
clockDiv.text( /* your text */ ); // set the text of the selected element to the passed argument
```

jQuery is a library the abstracts the Web APIs to help with cross-browser compatibility issues and to generally make navigating and manipulating the DOM a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
to set text in a div
```

$('#clock').text('some text');

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery returns the document information differently.  If I remember correctly it would have to be:

```
$(document)[0].getElementById('clock');
```

Comment: really? why somebody might want to do that, it would be much easier to use `var clockDiv = $('#clock')[0];`

Comment: I don't know - I think your answer is better. :-)  But it does answer the question.

Comment: The statement *"jQuery returns the document information differently"* makes no sense at all. `$(document)[0]` still returns `document`

Comment: Yes it does make sense.  $(document) (and not $(documnt)[0]) returns the document information differently.  It returns it as an object array which is why you have to put the [0] on the end of it.  Your statement makes no sense because the person asked why $(document)... didn't work.  As Arun posted - the first way returns an object - not the DOCUMENT object.